# Regex replace part of url with string only when url doesn't start with http://

Tags: php, regex, substitution

Tried to find the answer on stack**overflow** but I'm a complete RegEx noob!

All I need (if it's possible) is to match a PDF URL in some HTML and if it doesn't start with `http://` add `/content/` to the start, if it does start with `http://` do nothing.

Comment: That doesn't require a regex. You can check start of URL for presence of text `http://` in the language of your choice and if it is not there prepend `content/` in it.

Comment: You haven't specified what platform you're using, do you want to do this with javascript, or server-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you want is probably

```
http://add/content/\S+?\.pdf
```

Which says it must start with "http://add/content/" then can have anything which isn't a whitespace until it hits a .pdf at the end.
      Depending on what language you use you will need to apply this differently.  For example in php it would be

```
preg_match_all('|http://add/content/\S+?\.pdf|',$html,$matches);
if(count($matches)) {
     //do stuff with the matches in the $matches array
} else {
     //there were no matches of that form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do this with javascript.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    var link = links[i];
    var href = link.getAttribute("href");
    if(!/^http/.test(href))
    {
        link.setAttribute("href", "/content/" + href);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code - I wanted to do server side, to remove the need for JS to be enabled on the client side. Thank you though :)